# *++*++ppp, *++pp[1], *++(*(1+ppp) Is there any specific difference?(C/C++ pointer problem)

Tags: c++, c, pointers

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char *p[] = { "aa", "bb", "cc" };
    const char **pp[] = { p + 2, p + 1, p };
    const char ***ppp = pp;

    printf("%s\n", **++ppp );  // bb
    printf("%s\n", *++*++ppp);  // bb
    printf("%s\n", *++pp[1]);   // cc
    // printf("%s\n", *++(*(1+ppp)));   wrong

    return 0;
}
```

Microsoft VS2015 Output:
bb
bb
cc
Execution exception: 0xC0000005

`*++*++ppp`, `*++pp[1]`, `*++(*(1+ppp)` Is there any specific difference? Isn't `*++ppp` not `pp[1]`? Isn't `*++ppp` not `*(1+ppp)`? 
Thank you!

Comment: In C++ `char *p[]` needs to be `const char *p[]` (or my personal favorite `char const* p[]`)

Comment: Start by compiling it and read the warnings.

Comment: Why is `*++(*(1+ppp)));   wrong`?

Comment: @KamilCuk yes, Exception: 0xC0000005

Comment: @Lundin Sorry, I am careless.I use Microsoft VS IDE, no const is no warnings

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry, I am careless.I use Microsoft VS IDE, no const is no warnings

Comment: `*++*++ppp, *++pp[1], *++(*(1+ppp)` anyone writing this kind of expressions should be lifetime barred  from programming :)

Comment: @P__J__ This is just an example of a problem, in order to understand the pointer better.

Comment: You will understand it better if you write operations in the human readable and understandable form, not this "pseudo smart" tricky, shorthand way. If one needs to think more than 2 seconds to understand the expression - it is the sign of the bad style of coding. Bad style of coding leads to errors.

Comment: I recommend you draw it all out using pen and paper. Boxes for the arrays and strings, and arrow for the pointers. And remember that for any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is exactly equal to `p[i]`. And due to the commutative properties of addition, `*(p + i)` is equal to `*(i + p)` (which helps with `*(1 + ppp)`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for your advice. Actually, I have been thinking for a long time.I think *++*++ppp is equal to *++*(ppp+1), equal to *++pp[1]; but why is it not equal?

Comment: @FredHu The issue isn't the lack of const but the invalid C syntax. Don't use VS I guess, use a standard compliant compiler... because this code isn't valid C.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Yes there is a big difference between `*++p` and `p[1]`. The former *increments the pointer* before dereferencing it, the latter dereferences the elements after the pointed to element. The returned value is the same, but in the first case the pointer *is changed*.

---

**Important note:** Never ever write lines like these in production code! You can do this in experimental and fool's code. But professional code has to be clear and up-front understandable.

I know of several style guides that forbid using increment operators inside other expressions. They have to be on their own lines.

---

Let's dissect all your lines and look what they do to your variables.

```
printf("%s\n", **++ppp ); // *(*(++p))
```

`ppp` is incremented and points to `pp[1]`. That's contents points to `p+1` which points to `"bb"` which is printed. Check.

```
printf("%s\n", *++*++ppp); // *(++(*(++ppp)))
```

Again `ppp` is incremented and points to `pp[2]`. The derefence and pre-increment let it point to `p+1`. That's contents points to `"bb"` which is printed. Check.

```
printf("%s\n", *++pp[1]); // *(++(pp[1]))
```

This time you increment `pp[1]` which points to `p+2` thereafter. `pp` itself can't be incremented because it's an array so `pp[1]` is incremented. OK, `p+2` points to `"cc"` which is printed. Check.

```
printf("%s\n", *++(*(1+ppp))); // *(++(*(1+ppp)))
```

The sum `1+ppp` points to `pp[3]` which is **after** the array `pp`. Remember, you incremented `ppp` twice before! Dereferencing this pointer is undefined behaviour and can deliver any value. That value is then interpreted as a pointer to `const char **` which you try to increment and dereference once more. Somewhere here this results in an invalid pointer so a segmentation error is thrown. Boom.

---

And this is what you could have done to investigate your problem to understand how pointers and arrays of pointer work:

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

void print_pointers(const char *p[], const char **pp[], const char ***ppp)
{
    printf("p   = %p : %p %p %p\n", p, p[0], p[1], p[2]);
    printf("pp  = %p : %p %p %p\n", pp, pp[0], pp[1], pp[2]);
    printf("ppp = %p\n", ppp);
}

int main()
{
    const char *p[] = { "aa", "bb", "cc" };
    const char **pp[] = { p + 2, p + 1, p };
    const char ***ppp = pp;

    print_pointers(p, pp, ppp);
    printf("%s\n", **++ppp );  // bb
    print_pointers(p, pp, ppp);
    printf("%s\n", *++*++ppp);  // bb
    print_pointers(p, pp, ppp);
    printf("%s\n", *++pp[1]);   // cc
    print_pointers(p, pp, ppp);

    const char ***p1 = 1+ppp;
    printf("      1+ppp   = %p\n", p1);
    const char **p2 = *p1;
    printf("    *(1+ppp)  = %p\n", p2);
    ++p2;
    printf(" ++(*(1+ppp)) = %p\n", p2);
    const char *p3 = *p2;
    printf("*++(*(1+ppp)) = %p\n", p3);
    printf("%s\n", p3); // printf("%s\n", *++(*(1+ppp)));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I forgot the first "printf("%s\n", \**++ppp );", **ppp itself added 1**; so I always think of the second "printf("%s\ n", *++*++ppp); " should output "cc"